# PhoneGap To Bridge Mobile Platform

Tags: cordova

Would you rather develop apps with the PhoneGap framework, or concentrate solely on a specific mobile phone platform?

Thanks in advance,

sri

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let people know which platforms you are interested in developing for.

Coming to your question, PhoneGap is an open-source development tool for mobile platforms like iPhone, Android, BlackBerry, Palm, and Windows Mobile.

PhoneGap is solely designed to bridge the gap between web applications & mobile devices using only HTML, JavaScript & CSS.

On the iPhone platform, we can turn the web applications to look like a native iPhone app using this PhoneGap framework.

For complete information on PhoneGap, go to [phonegap.pbworks](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/)

Comment: Nice comment, From your comment, we need to install phoneGap for each device separately and run the HTML, CSS, JS files right?

Comment: Hi sri, there is no need to install PhoneGap for each device separately.  http://wiki.phonegap.com  will provide you the complete information regarding Phonegap. you can download phonegap from this link too. After installing PhoneGap on your PC, open it, you can see the folders for android, iphone, blackberry too. From there, you can run the file basing on your mobile platform. All the Best for your development..